# How to express $x^{k-1}\partial_x^k\left(\frac{F}{e^x-1}\right)$ in terms of $W=x^{k-1}\partial_x^k\left(F\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm dealing with a kind of $k$-th momentum $W=x^{k-1}\partial_x^k\left(F\right)$, and I want to express $x^{k-1}\partial_x^k\left(\frac{F}{e^x-1}\right)$ in terms of $W$. For instance, the continuous version (our case is the discrete version) can be dealt with as following;

$$
x^{k-1}\partial_x^k\left(\frac{F}{x}\right)=x^{k-1}\partial_x^k\left(\int_0^1\partial_xF(rx,t)dr\right)=x^{k-1}\int_0^1r^{k}\partial_x^{k+1}F(rx,t)dr$$

$$=\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^x\partial_x^{k+1}z^k\partial_x^{k+1}F(z,t)dz=\frac{W}{x}-\frac{k}{x^2}\int_0^xW(z,t)dz.
$$

My questions is how we can do the same thing for $x^{k-1}\partial_x^k\left(\frac{F}{e^x-1}\right)$. Of course, the equality is the best, but any inequalities would be great as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show explicitly how $\left(\frac{F}{x}\right) = \int_0^1\partial_xF(rx,t)dr $? I get an additional $r$ that needs to be integrated over.